# Using POST for flask url

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I've been looking at other stack questions but I am still confused on a concept that I think is very simple to most people on here. Basically, I'm trying to understand how my data from my form will post to my url route when `form.validate_on_submit`. Apologies in advance for bad terminology with Get/Post

I have the following form using WTForms:

```
class Info(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[Length(0, 64)],filters=[lambda x: x or None])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Then in my views.py I use the form.

```
@main.route('/people/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def person():
    form = Info()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        return redirect(url_for('.find_person', name=name))
    return render_template('mytemplate.html', form=form)
```

I would want the url to post to something like @main.route/people/. 
Then in find_person() I would be able to use request.form to get the arguments. Thanks in advance

Comment: request.form is only available in the view that is is POST'ed to by the form's action url.  So, find_person() will not have access to request.form since you are merely redirecting to it (not POST'ing to it).  Why can't you pass the form.name to the url as you are already doing in url_for?

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML template, when setting up your form tags, make sure it looks like:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('people') }}" method="post">
  <...content of your form here...>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> > I'm trying to understand how my data from my form will post to my url route when `form.validate_on_submit`

Your form data is implicitly fetched from [`flask.request.form`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.form) during the construction of your `Info` object. From the doc for [`flask_wtf.Form.__init__`](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-flask_wtf): "If `formdata` is not specified, this will use `flask.request.form`. Explicitly pass `formdata = None` to prevent this."